# Implemented Facebook Login But Other Buttons Doesn't Work

Tags: java, android, button, facebook-login

I implemented Facebook login from it's own tutorial. I have three buttons on my xml file. Which are Register, Login and Facebook Login. My MainActivity class is below. I can't use my register and login buttons. Only Facebook Login button is working. How can I use these buttons with Facebook Login button?

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity  {
Button b,b2;
TextView tv;
private MainFragment mainFragment;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    b = (Button)findViewById(R.id.loginbutton);
    b2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.registerbutton);

    b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, LoginPage.class));

        }
    });

    b2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, RegisterPage.class));

        }
    });

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {             // if I commend this if/else block,
        // Add the fragment on initial activity setup  // other two buttons are working 
        mainFragment = new MainFragment();             // fine.
        getSupportFragmentManager()
        .beginTransaction()
        .add(android.R.id.content, mainFragment)
        .commit();
    } else {
        // Or set the fragment from restored state info
        mainFragment = (MainFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
        .findFragmentById(android.R.id.content);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are adding a fragment to your activity which is likely over taking the MainActivity. Are you using MainFragment? Either move your buttons into MainFragment or remove the fragment from the activity.